# HowTo: Set Up Domain to Controller (Laravel, Ci ,Kohana)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing, kohana

How to Set Up domain

`hanomblog.com`

to a controller

`hanomwuruk.com/controller_blog`

So

`hanomwuruk.com/controller_blog` = `hanomblog.com`

(in CI, Laravel, or Kohana)

Answer (score 0):

In the `controller_blog` just redirect to the domain:

```
header('Location: http://hanomblog.com/');
die;
```

If that does not help then put some more effort into describing the problem. Writing in sentences and explaining in greater detail what you are trying to do would be a good start.

Comment: it's the same way with the **Addon domain** in cPanel?

Comment: What does this have to do with cPanel? It is just a simple redirect.